# Deploying on heroku, uninitialized constant BaseController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have the next error when adding my application to heroku,

```
/app/app/controllers/networks_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant BaseController (NameError)
2012-05-21T16:59:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:417:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2012-05-21T16:59:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:416:in `each'
2012-05-21T16:59:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:416:in `block in eager_load!'
2012-05-21T16:59:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:414:in `each'
2012-05-21T16:59:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:414:in `eager_load!'
2012-05-21T16:59:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:51:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2012-05-21T16:59:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2012-05-21T16:59:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2012-05-21T16:59:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2012-05-21T16:59:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2012-05-21T16:59:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2012-05-21T16:59:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
2012-05-21T16:59:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2012-05-21T16:59:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2012-05-21T16:59:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
2012-05-21T16:59:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-05-21T16:59:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-05-21T16:59:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
2012-05-21T16:59:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-05-21T16:59:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2012-05-21T16:59:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2012-05-21T16:59:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2012-05-21T16:59:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2012-05-21T16:59:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
2012-05-21T16:59:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
2012-05-21T16:59:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2012-05-21T16:59:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:54:in `block in <top (required)>'
2012-05-21T16:59:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
2012-05-21T16:59:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
2012-05-21T16:59:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
2012-05-21T16:59:06+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2012-05-21T16:59:07+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-05-21T16:59:07+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: What's at line 1 of networks_controller.rb?

Answer (score 1):

So your `networks_controller` inherits from `BaseController`. Is `BaseController` added to git?

Could you provide more info? At least a source of `NetworksController`.